# Failing Drupal 8 functional tests on drupalLogin()

Tags: drupal, phpunit, drupal-8, functional-testing, lando

I'm getting failures on **any** functional phpunit tests in Drupal 8 using the *drupalLogin()* function.  The resulting message is:

```
User tBQjiDPm successfully logged in.   
Failed asserting that false is true.  

/web/core/tests/Drupal/KernelTests/AssertLegacyTrait.php:35  
/web/core/tests/Drupal/Tests/UiHelperTrait.php:254
```

I traced the *drupalLogin()* function in UiHelperTrait.php and it appears line 253:
`$account->sessionId = $this->getSession()->getCookie(\Drupal::service('session_configuration')->getOptions(\Drupal::request())['name']);` is not being set.

My feeling is that sessions and/or cookies aren't being properly set when functional tests are being executed.

Drupal 8 is updated to the latest version (8.7.3) and I'm running PHPUnit 6.5.14.  Also, this is running off PHP 7.2 and nginx in Lando.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just curious, isn't Phpunit 7.5.x more appropriate for the PHP 7.2 version in use and the time of asking the question?

Comment: PHPUnit 6.5 is recommended for PHP 7.2.  See [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/phpunit)

Comment: I read that Drupl 8 on PHP 7.2 uses Phpunit 6.5. If that still is the case than this pins the Phpunit version (so no recommendation, it's just how it is). Thanks for clarifying. To your original question, as you've already found out that the helpers do not set everything you expect, maybe there is a mechanism for faking the session data you're looking for? Setting cookies might not be necessary in tests (in general), if there is no HTTP interaction, but I don't know the Drupal test-suite in specific.

Answer (score 4):

This was failing because in phpunit.xml, I had set **SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL** to **https**.  When I changed it to **http**, the functional tests were working!  I'm unsure whether this is a bug in Lando or if SimpleTest just isn't compatible with https.

Comment: Thanks. It saved me a lot of time

Comment: FWIW, in June 2023, I received the `Failed asserting that false is true.` error during the login method, and I had to switch SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL from **http** to **https** -- the reverse of the answer from Aug 2019.